# Swift init Array with capacity

Tags: arrays, swift

How do I initialize an Array in swift with a specific capacity?

I've tried:

```
var grid = Array <Square> ()
grid.reserveCapacity(16)
```

but get the error

```
expected declaration
```

Comment: You're getting that error because you're making a method call outside of a function (in a class, struct, enum or at the top level). Try this inside a function, or, move the reserveCapacity call into the init() method of your class.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Swift 3 / Swift 4 / Swift 5**

```
var grid : [Square] = []
grid.reserveCapacity(16)
```

I believe it can be achieved in one line as well.

Comment: I had issues with accepted answer with `repeating: nil` so this was a better option for me.

Comment: Why the optionality? As written this does nothing

Comment: I really think that this should be the accepted answer. The other answers create already initialized arrays, even if pre-populated with nils, still an array of count n. It should be noted though that the call to `reserveCapacity` should be placed in a function as the OP was having problems with the place of this function call.

Comment: This answer is VERY wrong. In this case, grid is nil. Which means the `reserveCapacity(16)` never actually gets called due to the way optionals work. The grid needs to be initialized. `var grid : [Square]? = []`

Comment: @Brett if you read the question the main pain point is initialising array with specific capacity. I assumed this question is not looking for an answer about just initialising one. 
Thanks for the addition though, feels it's worth mentioning that you need to initialise the array to use it.

Comment: @MertCelik I do understand the question, but many new developers might follow the example, and not realize that reserveCapacity wasn't actually called. If it was edited so that the array was initialized on the first line all would be good.

Answer (score 54):

How about:

```
class Square {

}

var grid = Array<Square>(count: 16, repeatedValue: Square());
```

Though this will call the constructor for each square.

If you made the array have optional Square instances you could use:

```
var grid2 = Array<Square?>(count: 16, repeatedValue: nil);
```

---

EDIT: **With Swift3 this initializer signature has changed to the following**:

```
var grid3 = Array<Square>(repeating: Square(), count: 16)
```

or

```
var grid4 = [Square](repeating: Square(), count: 16)
```

Of course, both also work with `Square?` and `nil`.

Comment: I found that it just call `Square()` for once. So all the instances in this array point to the same reference.

Comment: This is not correct. This creates an Array with 16 values. OP asked to create a new empty array with the _capacity_ to hold 16 values. I believe that this cannot be accomplished in Swift. You can only create the empty array _and_then_ reserve the capacity.

Answer (score 14):

```
var actions:[AnyObject?] = [AnyObject?](count: 3, repeatedValue: nil)
```

Answer (score 5):

**WARNING**:

If you use the `Array(repeating:count:)` initializer, you will encounter odd and unexpected behavior when using common array methods such as `append(` which will immediately defeat the purpose of reserving capacity by adding the new value outside the created capacity instead of an earlier point in the array.

**BETTER PRACTICE**:

Swift arrays dynamically double to meet the storage needs of your array so you don't necessarily need to reserve capacity in most cases.  However, there is a speed cost when you don't specify the size ahead of time as the system needs to find a new memory location with enough space and copy over each item one by one in `O(N)` speed every time it doubles.  On average, reallocation tends towards big `O(LogN)` as the array size doubles.

If you reserve capacity you can bring the reallocation process down from `O(N)` or `O(NlogN)`  on average down to nothing if you can accurately anticipate the size of the array ahead of time.  [Here is the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1538966-reservecapacity).

You can do so by calling `reserveCapacity(:)` on arrays.

```
var myArray: [Double] = []
myArray.reserveCapacity(10000)
```

Because array capacity expands as needed and fast, this really isn't necessary in a vast majority of cases.

For 99.9% of use cases attempting to manually control this will not provide any noticeable performance improvements if any at all, and isn't worth the trade off of confusing other developers that will have to wonder why you were so concerned with this.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var grid = Array<Square>(count: 16, repeatedValue: aSquare)
```

Comment: That sets size *and* capacity. OP wants size = 0.