# In Swift, can I write a generic function to resize an array?

Tags: swift

I have this function:

```
func sizeArray(inout array:Array<String>, size:Int) {

    while (array.count < size) {
        array.append("")
    }

    while (array.count > size) {
        array.removeLast()
    }
}
```

It works, but only with Array of String, can I make it generic to work with any type?

Comment: What do you expect to be able to fill a given array with an arbitrary `Element` type with? (what if I gave you a `[Never]`?)

Comment: i think that this will help you [Swift init Array with capacity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24124560/6689101)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*The most generic method...*

1. `Array` adapts `RangeReplaceableCollection` protocol which include methods which can help resizing. (No need to use a loop)
2. You need to construct new instances of the element when you grow the array. So you either provide a default value...

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    public mutating func resize(_ size: IndexDistance, fillWith value: Iterator.Element) {
        let c = count
        if c < size {
            append(contentsOf: repeatElement(value, count: c.distance(to: size)))
        } else if c > size {
            let newEnd = index(startIndex, offsetBy: size)
            removeSubrange(newEnd ..< endIndex)
        }
    }
}

var f = ["a", "b"]
f.resize(5, fillWith: "")    // ["a", "b", "", "", ""]
f.resize(1, fillWith: "")    // ["a"]
```

3. or you create a protocol that provides the default value `init()`. Note that you need to manually adapt the protocol to every types you care about.

```
public protocol DefaultConstructible {
    init()
}

extension String: DefaultConstructible {}
extension Int: DefaultConstructible {}
// and so on...

extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Iterator.Element: DefaultConstructible {
    public mutating func resize(_ size: IndexDistance) {
        resize(size, fillWith: Iterator.Element())
    }
}

var g = ["a", "b"]
g.resize(5)
g.resize(1)
```

Comment: you stole my idea i was just writing that anyway im voting up

Comment: consider of some refactoring (code in comments looks horrible ) :  `let distance = endIndex.distance(to: size)
        if distance < 0 {
            removeLast(-distance)
        } else if distance > 0 {
            append(contentsOf: repeatElement(value, count: distance))
        }`

Comment: @Silmaril: Although `removeLast` is listed in the doc https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/rangereplaceablecollection#default-implementations, trying to use it causes `Ambiguous reference to member 'removeLast()'` error (at least in Playground). Not sure what is going on.

Comment: @kennytm oh sorry, I didn't realize that

Comment: I tried my code in playground with an Array extension and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I've made one tweak to your method. As @Hamish mentioned in comments, you can't fill an array of any type with a string, so I am passing in the 'filler' to the function as well.

```
func sizeArray<T>(_ array:inout Array<T>, with filler:T, to size:Int) { 
    while (array.count < size) {
      array.append(filler)
    }
    while (array.count > size) {
      array.removeLast()
    }
}
var ints:[Int] = []
sizeArray(&ints, with: 3, to: 3)

var strings:[String] = ["a","b","c","d"]
sizeArray(&strings, with: "E", to: 3)
```

I've also updated the parameter names to match [Swift conventions](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjnwYWtxdnSAhUCEJAKHdmgDMMQygQIJTAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fswift.org%2Fdocumentation%2Fapi-design-guidelines%2F%23parameter-names&usg=AFQjCNHcZUXDm1rlcyAHYB-6BDV0xRruEA&sig2=MqslUb8bxEIoxmpcBSBvTw&bvm=bv.149397726,d.Y2I).

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect job for an extension

```
extension Array {
    mutating func resize(to size: Int, with filler: Element) {
        let sizeDifference = size - count
        guard sizeDifference != 0 else {
            return
        }
        if sizeDifference > 0 {
            self.append(contentsOf: Array<Element>(repeating: filler, count: sizeDifference));
        }
        else {
            self.removeLast(sizeDifference * -1) //*-1 because sizeDifference is negative
        }
    }

    func resized(to size: Int, with filler: Element) -> Array {
        var selfCopy = self;
        selfCopy.resize(to: size, with: filler)
        return selfCopy
    }
}

var ints: [Int] = [1]
ints.resize(to: 3, with: 3)
print(ints) //"[1, 3, 3]"

var strings = ["a","b","c","d"]
var resizedStrings = strings.resized(to: 3, with: "E")
print(strings) //"["a", "b", "c", "d"]"
print(resizedStrings) //"["a", "b", "c"]"
```

Properly deals with value semantics, and doesn't have any unnecessary loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a generic function and provide a default values for the new elements:

```
func sizeArray<T>(array: inout [T], size:Int, defaultValue: T) {

    while (array.count < size) {
        array.append(defaultValue)
    }

    while (array.count > size) {
        array.removeLast()
    }
}

var a = [1,2,3]
sizeArray(array: &a, size: 5, defaultValue: 0)

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Array {
    mutating func resize(to newSize: Int, _ appending: ((Int) -> Element)) {
        assert(newSize >= 0, "newSize must be a non-negative number")
        if newSize < self.count {
            self = Array(self[0..<newSize])
        } else if newSize > count {
            let needed = newSize - count
            for i in endIndex..<endIndex + needed {
                self.append(appending(i))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given:

```
var names: [String] = ["Jim", "John"]
```

Shorter:

```
names.resize(to: 1) { "New Name \($0)"} // ["Jim"]
```

Longer:

```
names.resize(to: 5) { "New Name \($0)"} // ["Jim", "John", "New Name 2", "New Name 3", "New Name 4"]
```