# reserveCapacity(Swift) vs resize(C++)

Tags: swift

I try to convert C++ code to the Swift. I have such a method written in C++ (simplified example)

```
std::vector<int> list;

void foo() {
...
  while(isOk) {
    list.resize(10000); //resize do it's job only if list.capasity < requested size

    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      list[i] = i;
    }
  }
...
}
```

Swift side:

```
var arr: [Int] = []

do {
  while true {
    arr.reserveCapacity(10000)
    
    for i in 0..<10000 {
      arr[i] = i
    }
  }
}
```

Error is :

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

According to the documentation `reserveCapacity` allocates requested size, but why when I try to write something to the specific cell I got an error?

Comment: Hey :) Can you explain, why you need this? Especially since Arrays in Swift are „dynamic“ in size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42822128/6576315

Comment: @JasonRietzke I don't know swift, but it would seem to me that arrays being dynamic in swift is exactly why you'd want a way of reserving capacity. Dynamic allocation can get expensive so if you know up front how much you're going to allocate (even roughly), it can be much more efficient to reserve memory, than to let swift handle it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're confusing the *underlying storage* of the array from the *actual size* of the array.
Arrays in Swift are dynamic, so you can `append()` and the array will grow in size accordingly.
Internally, Swift manages how the underlying memory is allocated for you, so you don't need to think about it.

When you `reserveCapacity`, this is telling Swift you anticipate that the array will be of this size eventually so it should get the memory ready for you in advance.
It's essentially just a performance optimization that you don't normally need to make, unless you know an array will grow to a given size eventually.
This does not mean the array now has this memory initialized with values, so accessing an element out-of-bounds will cause a crash.

If you want an array that is pre-initialized with values, you can use the `init(repeating:count:)` [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init) like so:

```swift
var arr = Array(repeating: 0, count: 10000)
```

This will both allocate storage for 10,000 elements **and** initialize each value to `0`, so now you can access any index in this range safely.